# Using variadic functions

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, variadic-functions, variadic

I am trying to use some variadic functions in C++ using Visual Studio 2019 latest compiler (though my compiler may be a few versions out of date).

I am trying to write a function that logs out the function call and some information about it, and return the result of the function call.

```
template <template <class, class> typename Function, class ...Args>
    inline auto LogCall(std::string fun_name, Function<Args...> fun, std::string fun_param = "", Args... args) {
        auto temp{ fun(args...) };
        std::cout << fun_name << "of" << fun_param << "/t -> /t" << temp << '\n';
        return temp;
    }
```

At first, I just used `typename Function` but that didn't work, so then I tried using this template template form. Either way, I get an error about no overloaded version matches when I call it. I am trying to call it with another template function currently, but I want to be able to use this on any function, so I am thinking I may need two where one is some version of this template template one and one that does not use template template.

For an example of it being used I have a simple variadic max function that can be assumed works and uses the same variadic template format as seen in this function. Here is an example of the call:

```
LogCall((string)"Max", max, (string)"1, 2, 3", 1, 2, 3);
```

I have also tried passing the template arguments and it doesn't fix it:

```
LogCall((string)"Max", max<int, int, int>, (string)"1, 2, 3", 1, 2, 3);
```

Is there any suggestions as to what the error in this function is?

Comment: What is `max`??

Comment: `LogCall`'s first template parameter is a template that takes exactly two parameters. Does this `max` template take exactly two parameters?

Comment: C++ is in a bad state when it comes to passing around function templates and overload sets. If you can't/won't make `max` a function object instead of a function template, I'd recommend wrapping it in a lambda or having a macro on hand to do that. Once you have something you can actually pass around, `typename F` works just fine.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik max is another variadic so it is max<typename First, class ...Rest>.

Comment: So how exactly do you expect that to match a template that takes exactly two parameters, instead of a variadic template, like that? How exactly do you expect `max` to match `template<typename, typename>`?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I have not used a template template before and have not been able to se many examples, so I am not sure how to set it up to work the way I was looking for it to.

Comment: There's nothing too earth-shattering here.It should be intuitive that `template<typename, typename>` would only match a template that takes exactly two parameters.  Does "max<typeame First, class ...Rest>" sound like a template tat takes exactly two parameters? No, it does not.Hence the error.